# Changing number of posts per page on CPT-archive.php, have tried 20-30 code chunks so far

Tags: custom-post-types, php, archives, custom-post-type-archives

I've been trying to change the number of posts that is displayed on my CPT movie-review archive page and I've tried about 20 - 30 different variations (and even a few plugins), but no luck. It is **stuck at 5 posts**, even though I know I have 10. 
There is also no pagination. update: fixed that.

Most of the variations I've tried look something like this

```
function wpd_testimonials_query( $query ){
    if( ! is_admin()
        && $query->is_post_type_archive( 'reviews' )
        && $query->is_main_query() ){
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 15 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpd_testimonials_query' );
```

and adding this to functions.php doesn't change anything.

The setup so far:
child theme with functions.php & custom post type-archive.php
in that archive page I run the standard wordpress loop

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

update 2: changed number from 5 to 15 as it was confusing that it looked like I was trying to change it to what I am stuck at.

Comment: Are you using [paginate_links](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) or something similar in your cpt-archive.php?

Comment: No, I used a different more complicated method, but this was far easier. The pagination works now, thanks!

Comment: Step 1 would be to verify that your `pre_get_posts` action gets triggered, add a `die` inside the `if` condition and see if it halts execution when you visit that page.

Comment: @Milo Thanks, I added it like this 
`$query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );
die();`
and it loads just fine, so I guess it doesn't get triggered. Do you know why that could be? I have another function right below changes `pre_get_posts` that triggers just fine

Comment: are you sure you need `$query->is_main_query()`, there's not a custom-query in the `archive-reviews.php` file is there?

Comment: Somehow when I tested it again today, it does trigger. The page won't load at all. @Milo @admcfajn I tried removing it now, nothing changes. As far as I know it's just the normal wp loop `<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> articles <?php endwhile; endif; ?>`

Comment: [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) is a useful plugin for displaying exactly what query is being run on each page, and the different hooks which are being called. Activating this on your site may shed some light on what else is impacting your query.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew! I found a little gem in a file buried in my parent theme that messed it up, when I removed the hook it works just fine!

Comment: Glad to hear your found the cause :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Query Monitor suggested by [@Andrew](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/50767/andrew) (Thanks, Andrew!) I found a little gem in my parent theme that overrides everything set in my function.

I found out wordpress loads the child themes functions.php first
`myfunction{
$query->set( 'posts_per_page', 15 );
}`

so when it later loaded

`lameparentfunction{
$query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
}`
It undid the changes I did.

Answer (score 0):

Your `wpd_testimonials_query` function is limiting the query to 5 posts with this line:

`$query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );`

Changing this number to 10, 15, 20, whatever will limit the query to that many posts per page.

If you remove this line and don't set `posts_per_page` the default value of 10 will be used. This default value can be updated via the **Blog pages show at most** option from the **Settings > Reading** options page and this value will be applied to all archive pages site-wide.

It's also worth calling your function with a higher priority in case there's multiple functions running on the `pre_get_posts` hook.

`add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpd_testimonials_query', 1, 999 );`

Comment: The settings in settings > reading is set to 50.
As previously, I've tried at least 20 different variations of that code shared on this page and many others, I did however not change the number (5) when I pasted it here, but if that is confusing I'll go ahead and update it. I just tried setting it to 15 and nothing changes.

Comment: Tried changing the priority, it does not work.